Why are there so many primes in $F_{k-1}+F_{k+1}$ when $k$ is odd?
Let $F_{k}$ be the Fibonacci sequence and let $a_k=F_{k-1}+F_{k+1}$. It is observed that there are many primes in the sequence $\{a_k\}$ when $k$ is odd:

$F_2+F_4=4$ (even);
$F_4+F_6=11$ (prime);
$F_6+F_8=29$ (prime);
$F_8+F_{10}=76$ (even);
$F_{10}+F_{12}=199$ (prime);
$F_{12}+F_{14}=521$ (prime);
$F_{14}+F_{16}=1364$ (even);
$F_{16}+F_{18}=3571$ (prime);
$F_{18}+F_{20}=9349$ (prime);
$F_{20}+F_{22}=24476$ (even);
$F_{22}+F_{24}=64079=139\times 461$.

It is interesting that for small $k$'s, when $a_k$ is odd, it is often, but not always, a prime. Is there any reason behind this?

I would first check numerically whether this holds for longer than the first dozen cases. Small odd numbers are primes often anyway.

Also, $\gcd(F_n,F_{n+2})=1$, and both $F_n$ and $F_{n+2}$ often have several small prime divisors, so their sum can't have any of those divisors, increasing the chances that the sum will be prime.

@quarague, for an odd number between $9000$ and $10,000$, it is far more likely to be a composite than a prime; but $F_{18}+F_{20}=9349$ is a prime.

It is like claiming that all ODD numbers , except Squares , are Prime : $1\text{(Square)},3,5,7,9\text{(Square)},11,13,\cdots$ : The "Conjecture" seems true !

$F_{n-1} + F_{n+1} = L_n$ The n-th Lucas number right ?

@Aurel-BG: You are correct: $a = [1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, 123, 199, 322, \dots]$.

Some extension from Aurel-BG's observation, this is just asking which Lucas numbers are primes, also called Lucas primes. Both the Lucas primes themselves and the indices of the Lucas numbers that generate primes are indexed in the list of integer sequences OEIS.
There is it stated that a Lucas number can only be a prime if its index is either a power of 2 or a prime itself (note that this is a necessary not a sufficient condition). Powers of 2 have an asymptotic density of $O(\log(n)/n)$ and primes have asymptotic density $O(1/\log(n))$ meaning the proportion of indices of Lucas numbers that are prime is asymptotically bounded above by the proportion of all numbers that are prime. Whether that counts as many is up to the reader.

There are about $n/\log n$ primes up to $n$, and hence their density is $1/\log n$.

@Gary You are correct, thanks, fixed.
